# nth-child() not working wither material-ui

Tags: css, material-ui

Im trying to make two paragraphs have different background colors using nth-child. For the JSX I have

```
<div className={classes.paragraphs}>
    <p>Test 1</p>
    <p>Test 2</p>
</div>
```

For the CSS I have

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({

  paragraphs: {
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    "&:nth-child(1)": {
       backgroundColor: "green"
    }
  }
}));
```

With this CSS, both paragraphs have a blue background but the first one should have a green background.

Comment: try this - "& > p:nth-child(1)"

Comment: that worked if you want to post it as the answer. Thank you

Comment: great, happy to help!

Answer (score 5):

I would say try `"p:nth-child(1)"` instead of `"&:nth-child(1)"` because your childs are `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write scss outside the. Scss file. Try writing it like:

Paragraphs:nth-child(1): {
backgroundColor: "green"
}